# Django Rest Framework can't parse response with javascript

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a JQuery `.ajax()` request that tries to get the answer from the server. But I get an error

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of
>   the JSON data

So, this is the javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
        ...
         success: function(response){
             ...
         },
         error: function(response){
             let resp = JSON.parse(response);
             console.log(resp);  
             saveButton.html('<i class="fa fa-warning">' + response.error + '</i>');
         }
     });
```

So, this is the DRF Response:

```
class SaveStockitemsTable(APIView):

renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer,)

def post(self, request, retailer_id):
    if not activation_date_string:
        return Response({"error": "No activation_date_string found"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    if not table_data:
        return Response({"error": "No table data found"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Is the `renderer_classes` attribute not working, or, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: First, what's the response status code ?

Comment: @Linovia It is 400. And I can see the error: "No activation_date_string found" in the Firefox browser.

Comment: Your code sample here will just not work. You should update it to provide meaningful informations and ensure the code you paste here also has your issue.